Expo push notifications not appearing as banners on Android emulator
I'm working on an Expo React Native app and I'm having trouble getting push notifications to appear as banners on my Android emulator. The notifications are being received and show up in the notification tray, but they don't pop up as banners when the app is in the background or when the device is locked.
Here's my setup:
I'm using expo-notifications for handling push notifications.
I've set up a notification channel with high importance:
javascript
await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
  name: "default",
  importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.HIGH,
  vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
  lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
  showBadge: true,
  lockscreenVisibility: Notifications.AndroidNotificationVisibility.PUBLIC,
});

My notification handler is configured to show alerts:
javascript
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: true,
  }),
});


On the backend, I'm sending notifications with high priority:
javascript

// Improved sendPushNotification function
const sendPushNotification = async (expoPushToken, message) => {
  const notificationMessage = {
    to: expoPushToken,
    sound: "default",
    title: "New Connection Request",
    body: message,
    data: { message },
    android: {
      channelId: "default", // Ensure this matches your channel ID
      icon: "ic_notification",
      color: "#000000",
      priority: "high", // Ensure high priority for immediate display
      visibility: "public", // Make it visible on lock screen and in notifications tray
    },
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(notificationMessage),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending push notification:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

Despite these settings, I'm not seeing banner notifications on the Android emulator. The notifications are received and appear in the notification tray, but they don't pop up as banners.
Is there something I'm missing in my configuration? Or is this an emulator-specific issue? How can I get the notifications to appear as banners on Android?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
I tried the following:
Set up a notification channel with high importance (Notifications.AndroidImportance.HIGH).
Configured the notification handler to show alerts (shouldShowAlert: true).
Set the notification priority to "high" in the backend payload.
Tested with both foreground and background app states.
Ensured the emulator's notification settings allow for alerts and banners.
Expected behavior:
I expected push notifications to appear as banner alerts on the Android emulator, popping up at the top of the screen when the app is in the background or when the device is locked.
Actual result:
The notifications are being received and show up in the notification tray, but they don't pop up as banners. They're only visible when I pull down the notification shade, regardless of the app's state (foreground, background, or closed).
I've tested this on multiple Android emulator versions (API 28, 30, and 33) with the same result. The behavior persists even after restarting the emulator and reinstalling the app.
